# Cannot Insert into MySQL DB Value of Radio Button as String

Tags: php, mysql, insert, radio-button

Language: OO PHP 5+
DB: MySQL

I am trying to insert data from a form using radio buttons by getting their value and then inserting into a MySQL database. I can insert anything on the form that uses a textfield to collect data, but when I try to insert the value of a radio button the insert just leaves the corresponding db field blank. I am using this for as a parameter in my Insert statement (these fields are assigned at the top of the class):

```
$this -> myTextfield // this works
 $this -> myRadioButtonValue // this doesn't seem to grab the value as it inserts a blank entry.
```

An help much appreciated.

GF

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the database. Where does $this->myRadioButtonValue come from? The question is impossible to answer without more detailed info.

Comment: Apologies for lack of information. I was referring to a field in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have specified a `value` attribute for the radio  button eg:

```
<input type="radio" name="somename" value="my value goes here !" />
```

Comment: Yes I have done that. I can use this value and print it out to the screen, I just can't seem to insert it into the db.I know this is a simple syntax error but what it is I cannot see yet.

Comment: I fixed it. I had put a space between '$this' and '->'. Grrr!